# Discretize a point on the surrounding grid and maintain Gaussian distribution

Tags: dirac-delta-distributions, discrete

I now have a point located at x, and the value at that point is q(x). I want to discretize the point to the surrounding grid points and maintain a Gaussian distribution. A one-dimensional grid is fine. Is there any generally recognized good discrete method? Thank you.

[image: Gauss discretize]

As far as I know, B-spline does not satisfy Gaussian distribution, so B-spline is excluded. One method I found is D.E.Shaw's Midtown-splins, but it can only reach the third order, which cannot meet my needs. What is a better discrete interpolation method?

Comment: Something like a [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics))?

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, the method I need must come from Gauss kernal, but what I need is to interpolate from one point to many points, and most methods are continuous functions to discrete points, or discrete points to continuous functions

Comment: And why is either of the two methods you've found bad? Especially the the "discrete points to continuous functions" part, I fail to see why that would be bad in any way.